# How to pass a value to a variable created in Google Tag manager?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, zoho

I have created a variable in GTM code to fetch emails but It needs to collect the data from the thankyou page Script. I have used Zoho forms to do this. Can somebody help?

Here's the function I'm using:

```js
function() { 
  try { 
    var searchEmail = function(input) { 
      for(i=0; i<input.length; i++) { 
        email = input[i].value; 
        if(email.match(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i)) { 
          return email; 
        } 
       } 
    } 
    return searchEmail({{Form Element}}); 
  } catch(e) { 
    return ""; 
  } 
}
```

The idea is that the code you put in on the thank-you page passes the `emailInput` variable to the script you put in the thank-you page.

Comment: DATA not Date.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: function() {
    try {
      
  var searchEmail = function(input){
  
     for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
       
    email = input[i].value;
        if(email.match(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i)){
          return email;
        }
     }  
  }
  return searchEmail({{Form Element}});
    }catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}

the idea is that the code you put in on the thank-you page passes the emailInput var to the script you put in the thank-you page